# Update text file with the name and also run an exe using batch file

Tags: file, batch-file

I would like to do below things for every single file for all the the files with the ext .mtc inside a particular directory in a loop using batch script. Can someone please help?

1. Output the name of file in a text file in a variable
2. Run my application exe
3. Pass the file name variable from the text file (in step 1) to another batch file so that it can be used to output the same from my 2nd batch file

*Basically i want to retain the name of the file stored in my 1st batch file to my 2nd batch file

I am able to do step 2 of running my application for each of the mtc file but not able to do step 1 and step 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this :

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b/a-d *.mtc') do call:execute "%%a"
exit /b
:execute
echo Treating : %1
Yourexe.exe
call your_second_bat.bat %1
```

And your second batch will get the value of the .mtc file in %1

your_second_bat.bat :

```
@echo off
echo Value received from My first bat is [%~1]
```

Comment: Thanks i wrote the below script and i tried to output in my text file but it gives me below o/p. 
I only want the filename without quotes. script i wrote @echo off for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.mtc') 
do call:execute "%%a" :execute echo Filename:%1 >> A.txt Output is as below 
Filename:"filename1.mtc" 
Filename:"filename2.mtc" 
Filename:

Comment: Try : echo %~1 >>A.txt

Comment: Thanks that removed quotes.. Just that i get last record - Filename: after the script executes.. how can it be taken out?

Comment: I don't anderstand what you mean. Try to explain it better

Comment: i mean i have only 2 files with ext mtc in my folder still i get 3rd empty record "Filename :- " which is not desired